# Unexpected end of JSON input node.js jason.parse()

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to parse JSON that is sent back with the following(PHP);

```
$UserData = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Discord WHERE RobloxID=".$UserId) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
    $result = $UserData->fetch_array();
    if (!is_null($result[RobloxID])) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'Username'  =>  $result[Username],
            'Code'      =>  $result[Code],
            'DiscordID' =>  $result[DiscordID],
            'IsVerified'=>  $result[IsVerified],
            'RobloxID'  =>  $result[RobloxID],
            )
        );
    } else {
        //$code = substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) , 0, 8);
        //$UserData->query("INSERT INTO Discord (Username,Code,DiscordID,IsVerified,RobloxID) VALUES ('$username','$code','$discordID','false','$UserId')");
        echo json_encode(array(
            'Username'  =>  'nil',
            'Code'      =>  'nil',
            'DiscordID' =>  'nil',
            'IsVerified'=>  'nil',
            'RobloxID'  =>  'nil',
            )
        );
    }
```

Here is the JSON created;`{"Username":"nil","Code":"nil","DiscordID":"nil","IsVerified":"nil","RobloxID":"nil"}`

I am using node.js to get what is returned;

```
request('http://example.net/API/verify.php?token=Nf_327&username=' + Username + '&UserId=' + UserID + '&discordid='+ msg.author.id, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred 
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received 
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        if (info.IsVerified == 'nil') {
            request('http://example.net/API/verify.php?token=Nf_328&username=' + Username + '&UserId=' + UserID + '&discordid='+ msg.author.id, function (error, response, body) {
                console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred 
                console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received 
                console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
            });
            msg.reply("Looks like its your first time trying to verify, I have DM'd you instructions on how to verify your account");
        }
    });
```

However whenever I try to run the function I get the error stack;`

```
Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Request._callback (/root/InfiusBot/commands/group/verify.js:41:22)
at Request.self.callback (/root/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

Any ideas as to what I am missing here? I am totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is occurring when JSON.parse is called. This means that the body that is returned is not proper JSON, which makes sense according to the request docs as it is a string that describes the content of the HTML page. This means that you are running JSON.parse on HTML and your url must be incorrect which you are making the request too. This could be because you are making the request to example.net? I feel that the base url should be a different URL.

Other methods to find the fault in your url is to check that when you visit the php page in your browser and pass it params the user object is visible on your screen. Then make sure that the url is correct. Then lastly you should check that your body object consists of JSON. If it does not print out some form of JSON, you should print the body and read through the HTML, as it could be an error that PHP is sending and for some reason was not caught by the error print that you have.